# Adding/removing viewcontrollers view

Tags: iphone

If I instantiate a lets say, UISegmentedControl. And link each button to add a viewcontrollers view to the viewhierachy, would it be enough to just add that view to the stack or must I call other methods aswell. And what about removing views? Would it be sufficient to just say

*I do NOT have the correct syntax in front of me right now so bear with me.*

```
[self removeSuperview];
```

Is it necassary to call methods on the viewcontroller itself?

Comment: So you are not using a navigationController or a modal view?

Comment: No, not in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a NavigationController and either push or present Modally the views. The you can just pop or dismiss them.

Comment: But what if I made a UIToolBar with UIBarButtonItems then?

Comment: exact same thing, you can always create a UINavigationController.

Comment: Okey, what would if I want the same "stack-principle" as the UINavigationController, but instead of the sliding effect(left/right) I want the view to fade in? I would say pushViewController and animation NO, but where do I put the animation code then?

Comment: Check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970632/fade-to-black-within-a-uinavigationcontroller